# how to solve:-listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use-

Tags: javascript, node.js

As I am trying to run the webservice shown as follows:

```
const port = 3000;
app.get('/hello', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('Hello, World!');
});
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('listening to port', port);
});
```

For the very first time, it works fine. But since then, when I run `node index.js` which contains the webservice mentioned above, I receive the error posted below.

To solve this issue I ran the following command:

```
npx kill-port 3000
```

but that did not solve the problem.

Please let me know if there is another way to solve this issue.

**Note**: I tried to use several other ports numbers, but I receive the same error message with the new port number indicated in the error message.

**Error**:

```
node:events:489
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
```

Comment: Some service on your computer is running on port 3000, so try to stop that one. Alternatively you could change your application from port 3000 to something else e.g. 3001 or 3002.

Comment: @Reyno please read the note section added above to the question, i tried what you suggested already

Answer (score 1):

It seems that port 3000 is already in use by another process.

If you use **Linux** as OS:

- For a list of listening ports

```bash
ss -ntlp
# or
netstat -ntlp
```

- To check specifically for port 3000

```
netstat -ntlp | grep ':3000'
```

Next, kill the process using the port (**check what it is first**).

```bash
kill <PID>
kill -9 <PID>  # if kill does not work
```

If you're using Windows or macOS, there's an equivalent way to list listening ports and kill the process using the desired port.

**Windows** :

```bash
netstat -ano | findstr :3000
taskkill /PID <PID> /F
```

**MacOS**:

```bash
lsof -ti:3000
kill <PID>
kill -9 <PID> # if kill does not work
```

Comment: Is there something about `npx kill-port 3000` that wouldn't work for this?

Comment: I don't know nodeJS, but a permission problem can lead to this, for instance : launching the first process with root rights, then launching `npx kill-port 3000` with user rights.

Answer (score 1):

Stop the process from Task Manager.

[end the task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI3zI.png)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the very first time is works fine & then it throws an error second time onwards.

It has to do with the way you are stopping the application if your doing `Ctrl + Z` (or `cmd + Z` on Mac) the app will be stopped on terminal but the process won't be killed.

The correct way is `Ctrl + C` (or `cmd + C` on Mac), it will send SIGINT which will kill the application.